# Build Mongo Cpp driver with SSL and prebuild Boost on Windows

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, openssl, driver

I'm having trouble building the Mongo legacy Cpp driver with the --SSL option on Windows.

The problem is that I'm using the *prebuild* versions of the Boost libraries thus as is detailed on the mongo driver build documentation page I must use the **--libpath** and **--cpppath** option to point to the boost libs and headers instead of the **--extrapath** option.

> Due to the layout of the boost installation in the pre-built binaries,
>   you cannot use the --extrapath SCons flag to inform the build of the
>   installation path for the boost binaries. Instead, you should use the
>   --cpppath flag to point to the root of the chosen boost installation path, and --libpath to point into the appropriately named library
>   subdirectory of the boost installation.

But I also need the **--libpath** and **--cpppath** to point to the OpenSSL library. 
I've tried:

- Combining the paths with a ';' *ex. --libpath="c:\boost-path\lib;c:\openssl-path\lib"*
- Specifying the **--libpath** and **--cpppath** twice, each with one
  path
- Set environment variables **LIBPATH** and **CPPPATH**

None seem to work, depending on what comes first I get a build warning about not finding Boost or not finding SSL.

How can I specify both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legacy driver build system honors several forms of setting the library and include search path. The one that you want to use here is the `LIBPATH` and `CPPPATH` Scons Variables, which are set *after* invoking SCons. Multiple arguments are separated with spaces within a quoted string. Try the following:

```
scons --ssl CPPPATH="c:\boost-path\include c:\openssl-path\include" LIBPATH="c:\boost-path\lib c:\openssl-path\lib"
```

Comment: Thanks!, this does the trick. But if a path contains spaces how would one deal with that? I've tried all the obvious things like putting the path between single quotes or using ';' or even using ['path1', 'path2'] but to no avail.

Comment: The string seen by SCons for these variables is fed to pythons shlex.split function. By default, it uses the 'other' mode on windows. There is a build flag that changes the default to posix, where you might be able to pull off some escaping that gets you there. Generally, I try to not use spaces on paths on Windows for exactly this reason.